# Weird Black Spot with Glossy Material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Why am I getting a black spot in the cylinder. The scene is nothing special consists of few objects with no materials except for the cylinder, and lighting comes from the environment map.

[image: Weird Black reflection]

The cylinder is smooth shaded and simply using a glossy material with the default settings.

[image: Glossy BSDF settings I have used]

Could this possibly have to do with render settings. I have tried re-adding the cylinder and creating a new glossy material but with the same results.

Comment: does your cylinder have a face at the end? If so that is what is causing the shading artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the smooth shading that you hve applied to the cylinder.
So you can try just adding a loop cut all the way to one end and then another loopcut all the way to another end.

Comment: Why is this the case? What makes it work internally after adding those loop cuts?